# Can't Live Migrate or move Hyper-V VM

Tags: windows, hyper-v, cluster, failovercluster, windows-cluster

we have a two-node Server 2019 Hyper-V cluster with an SSD SAN providing the shared storage.
I'm in the process of trying to update the host servers with their windows updates.

I planned to move all the VM's from Host-01 to Host-02 install the windows updates on Host-01, then move all the VM's to Host-01 and repeat the process on Host-02.

I managed to move all the VM's to Host-02 except 1 Server 2012 VM which when I try to do a live migrate gets to about 62% then simply stops migrating and remains on Host-01.

If I try to Move the VM instead of live migrating, it appears on Host-02 but with a big red X on it and it then refuses to start.

The event logs show the following errors:

> Event ID: 1205 - The Cluster service failed to bring clustered role <<'MY Server'>> completely online or offline. One or more resources may be in a failed state. This may impact the availability of the clustered role.

> Event ID: 1069 - Cluster resource 'Virtual Machine Configuration <>' of type 'Virtual Machine Configuration' in clustered role 'SVR-IIS-INTRA' failed.

> Event ID: 1254 - Clustered role '<>' has exceeded its failover threshold.....

> Event ID: 1205 - As above

> Event ID: 1069 - Cluster resource 'Virtual Machine Configuration <>' of type 'Virtual Machine Configuration' in clustered role '<>' failed. The error code was '0x5' ('Access is denied.').

> Event ID: 21502 - 'Virtual Machine Configuration <>' failed to register the virtual machine with the virtual machine management service.

```
The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to register the configuration for the virtual machine '03059663-1988-4147-929F-4D543925C4EA' at '\\host-01\c$\ClusterStorage\Volume1\<<My Server>>': General access denied error (0x80070005). If the virtual machine is managed by a failover cluster, ensure that the file is located at a path that is accessible to other nodes of the cluster.
```

The last 2 / 3 error events were generated when attempting a standard move rather than a live migrate.
I've checked that both hosts can access the above folder location so I'm at a bit of a loss.

If push comes to shove I will have to create a new VM and move the disk but if anyone knows how to fix this I'd be grateful.

To be clear I have over 40 VM's (20 per host) and this is the only one that is refusing to move. All VM's use the same CSV (1).

Thanks for any thoughts.

Paul.

Comment: Double check, if the affected VM does have an ISO attached or uses vswitch (name), which doesn't exists on second server.

Comment: he issue could be related to the incorrect permissions on the VHDX. Check the resolution here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v-virtual-machine-not-start-0x80070005
Of course, check all the prerequisites for successful Live Migration. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831435(v=ws.11)
 In addition, might be helpful: https://www.hyper-v.io/hyper-v-live-migrations-settings-ensure-best-performance/

Comment: Can you migrate this VM, if not all other VMs are already migrated? Maybe there are just not enough ressources.